# Append value to $request with add method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to modify a field value which passed from login form in my controller and then use it, I searched in Stackoverflow and google and found the `add()` method for adding a value to `$request` so I trying to add a parameter to `$request`:

```
$number = '+' . $country->code . $request->mobile;
$request->request->add(['number' => $number]);

if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

but when I use `dd($request->all())` to test `$request`, the `number` does not exists in `$request` .

What is the problem ?

Comment: Would it not be easier to just fetch the input into an array and then amend that array?

Comment: According to this article your method should work: http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-artificially-add-values-to-request-array/

Comment: `attemptLogin()` need an instance of `Request` as argument and I cannot pass an array

Comment: Where do you call the `dd`?

Comment: @mimo You right, I read that article before, but I cannot understand why this code not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge()` method:

```
$request->merge(['number' => $number]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Work like a charm !